# Apache 2.4 & Phusion Passenger generating 403 Error

Tags: linux, ruby-on-rails, apache-2.4, phusion-passenger, ruby

I'm trying to setup a Rails application ([Project Fedena](https://github.com/projectfedena/fedena)) on the following Server configuration. I am using the virtual host configuration below. I get a 403 when I visit the IP/Domain. There's only one user on this server, root.

Google Cloud - Ubuntu 14.04

- Rails 2.3.5
- Ruby 1.8.7
- Rubygems 1.3.7
- Apache 2.4
- Phusion Passenger version 5.0.2

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/fedena.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName enomy.com
        ServerAlias www.enomy.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /srv/fedena/public
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        <Directory "/srv/fedena/public">
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
                Options -MultiViews
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
        RailsEnv development
        RailsBaseURI /srv/fedena </VirtualHost>
```

**tail -f /var/log/apache2/***

> ==> /var/log/apache2/error.log <== [Wed Mar 11 22:00:01.715324 2015] [autoindex:error] [pid 31091:tid 140200239867648] [client
>   41.203.67.171:4958] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /srv/fedena/public/: No matching DirectoryIndex
>   (index.html,index.cgi,index.pl,index.php,index.xhtml,index.htm) found,
>   and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
>
> ==> /var/log/apache2/access.log <==
>   41.203.67.171 - - [11/Mar/2015:22:00:01 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 492 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,
>   like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.111 Safari/537.36"

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18106085/im-getting-403-error-using-passenger-for-rails-in-apache

Comment: Were you by chance able to solve this problem? I'm curious if you were able to run your rails two app on passenger. I'm having the same problem.

Comment: add an index file such as the description of the error log to the documentroot and see what happens. I don't really see an issue, you ask for a directory and you have no default page nor indexes allowed, that's normal behaviour!